# Is there a control that mimics iOS Contacts Add/Edit screen

Tags: ios, contacts

I want to know if there is any control that mimics iOS Contacts Add/Edit Screen,which i can customize for my own use.As it looks a little complex to build from scratch.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is none, as you can't really customize Apple's [ABPersonViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/index.html). I would subclass UITableViewController for that purpose. The [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) sample might come in handy.